# Problema al instalar Dot Net Core en Debian 9

Tags: debian, .net-core, debian-9

He seguido la [documentación oficial de Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial) para instalar Dot Net Core en el servidor, dice ejecutar los siguientes comandos:

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.asc.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list
sudo mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema viene al ejecutar el comando:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Dando como resultado el siguiente error:

```
Fetched 91.8 kB in 0s (103 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod/dists/stretch/InRelease
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

¿Qué hacemos, lloramos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, vamo a calmarno. En segundo lugar, el error dice lo siguiente:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
```

Tenemos que verificar si el paquete `apt-transport-https` está instalado, ésto se realiza mediante el siguiente comando:

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

Lo que nos da como resultado:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
Need to get 171 kB of archives.
After this operation, 243 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirrors.*************.com/debian stretch/main amd64 apt-transport-https amd64 1.4.8 [171 kB]
Fetched 171 kB in 0s (10.0 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package apt-transport-https.
(Reading database ... 108493 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt-transport-https_1.4.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt-transport-https (1.4.8) ...
Setting up apt-transport-https (1.4.8) ...
```

Sí, efectivamente, ese paquete estaba sin instalar, así que ahora vamos a probar nuevamente:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

¡Y tenemos la magia!

```
Get:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod stretch/main amd64 Packages [29.7 kB]
Fetched 32.6 kB in 0s (33.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

¡La emoción de ver que todo sigue avanzando!

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aspnetcore-runtime-2.1 dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-2.1 dotnet-runtime-2.1
  dotnet-runtime-deps-2.1 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 liburcu4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aspnetcore-runtime-2.1 dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-2.1 dotnet-runtime-2.1
  dotnet-runtime-deps-2.1 dotnet-sdk-2.1 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0
  liburcu4
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
Need to get 131 MB of archives.
After this operation, 379 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

Y luego de un rato tenemos:

```
Welcome to .NET Core!
---------------------
Learn more about .NET Core: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs

Telemetry
---------
The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. The data is anonymous and doesn't include command-line arguments. The data is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.

Read more about .NET Core CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry

Configuring...
--------------
A command is running to populate your local package cache to improve restore speed and enable offline access. This command takes up to one minute to complete and only runs once.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
```

Y por si las dudas, volvemos a verificar con el comando:

```
dotnet --info
```

Ahora sí, ¡con todo el power 2.0!

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.500
 Commit:    b68b931422

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  9
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.9-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.500/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.6
  Commit:  3f4f8eebd8

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.500 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Ahora sí todo en orden, que la fuerza os acompañe :D